# Ubuntu 20.04 stuck on boot screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, 20.04, dell

I recently bought a brand new DELL OptiPlex 7080 and set up windows 10 and ubuntu 20.04 togather (dual boot).
Ubuntu and windows booted perfectly while installation. After installation, I rebooted Ubuntu and then it booted up normally.
Then, finally I changed the Date/Time, Location settings and the rebooted the PC. And this time it stucks (the loader spins, so it was not hung). I waited for 15 minutes but it doesn't work. But windows is still working perfectly. How to fix this now?

Comment: Try reinstalling ubuntu? It sounds like the data may have corrupted.

Comment: @2-bituser I've reinstalled it twice, but it doesn't work

Comment: That's just what I've done to fix that problem on my pc, but since it does not work... I don't know what could be the problem in that case.

Comment: Can you remove `quiet splash` from the end of your command line? Press and hold Shift when the computer starts up to get to GRUB, highlight the entry (with the white rectangle) and press E, then use the keyboard arrow keys to navigate around. Once you've removed the words, press Control and X together to boot. What are the last messages printed to the screen?

Comment: @galexite There was no output

Comment: @ArRakin how about removing `quiet splash` and replacing it with `video=efifb earlyprintk=efi nomodeset`?